# VB.Net - How do I call a method on an object within a list of objects?

Tags: vb.net

I have created a program which allows the user to add people to a group. I have two classes TPerson and TGroup, using composition, TGroup can add people (TPerson) to a list of objects (Of TPerson). However, I am struggling to add new people (TPerson) to a Group list and call the methods of TPerson on the objects created.

```
    Public Class TGroup
        Private Group As List(Of TPerson)
        Private GroupSize As Integer
        Public Sub New(size As Integer)
            GroupSize = size
        End Sub
        Public Function GetGroupSize() As Integer
            Return GroupSize
        End Function
        Public Sub AddPersons()
            For i = 1 To GroupSize
                Group.Add(New TPerson()) 
                Group(i).AddPersonDetails() 'error seems to be around here
            Next
        End Sub
        Public Sub ShowPersons()
            For i = 1 To GroupSize
                Group(i).ShowPersonDetails()
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class TPerson
        Private Name As String
        Private Address As String
        Private Age As Integer
        Public Sub New()
            Name = "x"
            Address = "x"
            Age = 0
        End Sub
        Public Sub AddPersonDetails()
            Console.WriteLine("Input name: ")
            Name = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("Input age in years: ")
            Age = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("Input address: ")
            Address = Console.ReadLine
        End Sub
        Public Sub EditPersonDetails()
            Dim edit, newdata As String
            Console.WriteLine("Which data would you like to edit?")
            edit = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the data you would like to current " & edit & " with: ")
            newdata = Console.ReadLine
            If edit = "address" Or edit = "Address" Then
                 Address = newdata
            ElseIf edit = "name" Or edit = "Name" Then
                 Name = newdata
            ElseIf edit = "age" Or edit = "Age" Then
                 Age = newdata
            End If
            Console.WriteLine(edit & " successfully changed.")
        End Sub
        Public Sub ShowPersonDetails()
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " & Name)
            Console.WriteLine("Age in years: " & Age)
            Console.WriteLine("Address: " & Address)
        End Sub

   End Class


    Sub Main()
            Dim MyGroup As TGroup
            Dim NoOfPersons As Integer

            Console.WriteLine("How many persons in the group? ")
            NoOfPersons = Console.ReadLine
            MyGroup = New TGroup(NoOfPersons)
            MyGroup.AddPersons()
            MyGroup.ShowPersons()

            Console.Read()
    End Sub
```

When I run the program, I get an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Initialize private member `Group` in the constructor: `Group = New List(Of Person)` in the constructor

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for your comment. I tried this and an exception was thrown. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'  this was thrown on the line where I call the method Group(i).AddPersonsDetails()

Comment: This `For i = 1 To GroupSize`should be `For i = 0 To GroupSize-1`

Comment: Preciousbetine you genius! thank you. Do you mind explaining why this is? i thought the two were equivalent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must be pretty new to vb. I suggest you read about lists and arrays.

Comment: And remember that array's starting index in vb.net is 0. `For i = 0 To GroupSize - 1`

Comment: When you create your TGroup you pass in a Size. Let's say 4. Just like arrays, List(Of T) begin with index 0. So, the elements in the list would be indexes 0, 1, 2, 3. That is 4 elements with indexes 0-3. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah cleared that up. Thanks alot.